# Get rotation in Cesium

Tags: cesiumjs

I want to know the rotation angle from Cesium when I turn the map using ctrl+mouseLeft. Like I did on this image:
[image]

I tried `viewer.camera.roll` but doesn't seem to be right. It's always zero.

Any tips in how I can get that value in 2D and 3D? I would also like to set this value.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I have used the solution suggested and now I'm getting different values (in radians). It works both on 2D and 3D maps.

EDIT2: How to set the rotation to an specific angle

```
    setRotation(angle: number): void {
        viewer.camera.setView({
            heading: (angle / (180 / Math.PI)) // east, default value is 0.0 (north)
        })
    };
```

Based on this [doc](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Camera.html?classFilter=camera)

EDIT 3:
I'm using the following code to get the current heading of the map:

```
public getAngle(): number {
    return viewer.camera.heading;
}
```

When I call this function and my map is not rotated, as the image shows, I get the result of "6.283185307179586" radians. I thought it should be zero, because it's not rotated at all. If I move the map around with the mouse (pan) and call the getAngle function again it gives differents results, as "1.4612025367455317e-8" if I move it north. Any thoughts about it? I would like to get the heading of the map.

Thanks a lot!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This value is available from `viewer.camera.heading` and is expressed in radians.  You can twist the camera like this using the [twistLeft and twistRight](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Camera.html#twistLeft) functions on the camera.

Comment: Is there a way to define the radians I want to rotate? Insted of always adding some rotation to the current one? Let's say I want to define rotation to 30rad left. Is that possible or I have to calculate the current rotation and the requested one and adapt using twistLeft/twistRight?

Comment: Created function to set the value to rotate in the Edit on question

Comment: any thoughts on my output problem?